# How to change pagination numbers using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs (nextjs) and i am integrating "Nextjs" framework,I integrated pagination successfully but creating buttons like "1,2,3,20" but i want button should display "1,2...20" (Right now displaying all numbers,should use "..." after 2 buttons),how can i do this ? Here is my code in Allblogs.js

```
import Pagination from '../Pagination';
import { paginate } from "../../utils/paginate";
function Allblogs() {
  const pageSize = 1;
  const [posts,setPosts]=useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const { data: res } = await axios.get(
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      );
      setPosts(res);
      
    };
    getPosts();
  }, []);
  
  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  const paginatePosts = paginate(posts, currentPage, pageSize);
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [router.query]);
}
return (
    <>
      {paginatePosts.map((post, index) => {
              // displaing blogs data
  })} 
 <Pagination items={posts.length} pageSize={pageSize} currentPage={currentPage} onPageChange={handlePageChange} />
 </>
```

Here is my code in "Pagination.js"

```
import _ from "lodash";
const Pagination = ({ items, pageSize, currentPage, onPageChange }) => {
  const pageCount = items / pageSize;
  if (Math.ceil(pageCount) === 1) return null;
  const pages = _.range(1, pageCount + 1);
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <ul className="pagination">
          {pages.map((page) => (
            <li
              key={page}
              className={
                page === currentPage ? "page-item active" : "page-item"
              }
            >
              <a
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => onPageChange(page)}
                className="page-link"
              >
                {page}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```

Answer (score 1):

A very easy and effective way to handle the pagination in ReactJs/Nextjs, By using the [react-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate) library.

```
 <ReactPaginate
    breakLabel="..."
    nextLabel="next >"
    onPageChange={handlePageClick}
    pageRangeDisplayed={2}
    pageCount={200}
    previousLabel="< previous"
    forcePage = {CurrentPage}
  />
```

to set current page use - `forcePage = {PageNumber}` 
to set total Pages use - `pageCount = {200}` 
to handle click use - `onPageChange = {handlePageClick}`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library. I was trying to solve this using a custom hook.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const usePagination = (pageCount) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(1);
  const previous = current - 1;
  const next = current + 1;
  const last = pageCount;
  const first = 1;

  const hasBetweenPreviousAndFirst =
    next - current > 0 && current !== first && previous - first > 1;
  const hasBetweenNextAndLast =
    next - current > 0 && current !== last && last - next > 1;

  const onPageChange = (newPage) => {
    setCurrent(newPage);
  };

  return {
    previous,
    current,
    next,
    first,
    last,
    onPageChange,
    hasBetweenPreviousAndFirst,
    hasBetweenNextAndLast,
  };
};
```

Which I used like this in your `Pagination` component. I removed the state from the `Allblogs` component since the state is now handled by the custom hook. But you could pass it down and use it in the hook.

```js
const Pagination = ({
  items,
  pageSize,
}: {
  items;
  pageSize;
}) => {
  const pageCount = items / pageSize;
  if (Math.ceil(pageCount) === 1) return null;

  const {
    previous,
    current,
    next,
    first,
    last,
    onPageChange,
    hasBetweenPreviousAndFirst,
    hasBetweenNextAndLast,
  } = usePagination(items);

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="pagination">
        {current !== first && (
          <li className="page-item">
            <a
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => onPageChange(first)}
              className="page-link"
            >
              {first}
            </a>
          </li>
        )}
        {hasBetweenPreviousAndFirst && <li>...</li>}
        {previous > first && (
          <li className="page-item">
            <a
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => onPageChange(previous)}
              className="page-link"
            >
              {previous}
            </a>
          </li>
        )}
        <li className="page-item active">{current}</li>
        {next < last && (
          <li className="page-item">
            <a
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => onPageChange(next)}
              className="page-link"
            >
              {next}
            </a>
          </li>
        )}
        {hasBetweenNextAndLast && <li>...</li>}
        {current !== last && (
          <li className="page-item">
            <a
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => onPageChange(last)}
              className="page-link"
            >
              {last}
            </a>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```